# Try to store music for XBOX UWP on System

Tags: c#, uwp, storage, xbox, xbox-one

I'm writing a UWP Music player, that syncs Music stored in your OneDrive to the local machine to play it. The User can Store it in the App folder, or his Music Folder.

I also would like that this app runs on the XBoxOne. Unfortunately Storing Data on the System will quickly throw Not Enough Disk Space Exception.

According to an [MSDN Answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5ce2806c-fddd-426d-9252-7a6b4420f286/uwpxbox-what-storage-limit-is-for-uwp-apps-on-xbox) an app can have a maximum of 3GB and there seems to be ways to get it up to 16GB  if no other UWP app takes up that space.

A dedicated Music folder is not available on Xbox. (The method to get the `StorageFolder` returns null)

Is there any way to store more data on the Xbox? Some music library's exceed easily 50GB.

Comment: How much storage space do you need?

Comment: @XavierXie-MSFT Well, If I would wanted to store my collection on the harddrive it would be a little more the 50GB (still growing). This is way more then UWP apps normaly support. I'm not sure if the usecase "store all your music on the Xbox so you can hear it without Internet" is supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no support for apps to get additional space on the internal drive (there can be a user music folder, but space here is limited). The reason why you got a failure getting the music folder may because that you didn’t declare the capability. Since given the limited storage, I’d strongly discourage you from writing files there.

You can format an external USB drive to be used for media playback and plug it in, with apps being allowed to read from it if you have the capability defined in your manifest.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations

See above for declaring access to removable storage if you want to read from an external drive formatted for media.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the USB solution. My app should have the rights to access the music folder. Under Windows it works. But I didn't investigated further after the first try to access it. I just thought propably not available under XBox.